# Equivalent of R function 'ave' in Python Pandas

Tags: python, r, pandas

I have a dataframe in R. Example:

```
d1<-structure(list(A = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), B = 1:9), .Names     = c("A", 
"B"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

I want output like

```
d2<-structure(list(A = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), B = 1:9, 
c = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 9L)), .Names = c("A", 
"B", "c"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

I can do it in R using `ave` function.

```
d1$c<-ave(d1$B,d1$A,FUN=max)
```

Now I want to do it in python. I mean if I have data like d1, How can I create d2 in python pandas?

Comment: No Sir... No can do Sir. Please read [ask] .

Comment: "I have a dataframe in Pandas" I beg to differ, that's a DataFrame in R. Please show the pandas DataFrame and the expected output. I'm confused in what way (3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 9L) is the max of these two columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The R `ave` function (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/ave.html) applies the function (default is averaging) to combinations of observations with the same factors levels.

In pandas, there is no such function out of the box, but you can do this with a groupby operation.

Starting from your dataframe:

```
In [86]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3], 'B':range(1,10)})

In [87]: df
Out[87]: 
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  2
2  1  3
3  2  4
4  2  5
5  2  6
6  2  7
7  3  8
8  3  9
```

You can add a column C as the result of a grouping by `A` and calculating the max of `B` for each group:

```
In [88]: df['C'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('max')

In [89]: df
Out[89]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  1  3
1  1  2  3
2  1  3  3
3  2  4  7
4  2  5  7
5  2  6  7
6  2  7  7
7  3  8  9
8  3  9  9
```

Note: I use the transform method here because I want to end up with the same index as the original dataframe.

For more information on the groupby functionalities in pandas, see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html

Comment: Thanks you so much joris.

Comment: @joris I am getting a `Series object has no attribute error ` but this works `df['C'] = df.groupby('A').B.transform('max')`

Comment: @RTrain3k Thanks, apparently pandas' behavior changed here, and your alternative is better anyway, so updated the answer with that.